# Can I get a token with just php and not balanced.js?

Tags: php, balanced-payments

I am following the "credit bank account" example on [Balanced docs](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/?language=php#credit-a-bank-account).

I have already successfully made debit credit card, debit bank account, and credit bank account work using balanced.js in conjunction with php Curl.

But now I need a way to obtain the token without javascript. Javascript shows the bank account info on the client side, but I am paying you, and I cannot be allowed to see your bank account info.

So, I want to obtain the bank account token from server side. Is this possible?

From the example, I'm using:

```
var bankAccountData = {
    name: $form.find('input[name=ba-name]').val(),
    routing_number: $form.find('input[name=ba-rn]').val(),
    account_number: $form.find('input[name=ba-an]').val(),
    type: $form.find('select').val()
};  

balanced.bankAccount.create(bankAccountData, callbackHandler);
```

There is a potential problem with getting it using balanced.js. If I am a 'payer' and I am paying money to a 'payee', I can't use the above js code because as the 'payer', I shouldn't be seeing any account info relating to the 'payee'.

That is, someone viewing the source code could get that payee info.

Comment: Do you mean how do you retrieve a tokenized funding instrument from the API? This of course, it was tokenized (ideally through `balanced.js`).

Comment: I guess that's what I mean. From the example, I'm using: 

`var bankAccountData = {
  name: $form.find('input[name=ba-name]').val(),
  routing_number: $form.find('input[name=ba-rn]').val(),
  account_number: $form.find('input[name=ba-an]').val(),
  type: $form.find('select').val()
 }; 
  
 balanced.bankAccount.create(bankAccountData, callbackHandler);`

There is a potential problem with getting it using balanced.js. If I am a 'payer' and I am paying money to a 'payee', I can't use the above js code because as the 'payer', I shouldn't be seeing any account info relating to the 'payee'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Balanced.js is only for tokenizing credit cards and bank accounts. There is no way to retrieve the URI for a bank account through it. This needs to be done via the API. For example, to do this with the official Balanced PHP client library, https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=php#retrieve-a-bank-account

The returned object will not contain any sensitive bank account information.

Comment: I guess this question is obsolete since Balanced has gone under.